# Heroku - Python - Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, heroku

I'm running python 3.7.4 locally. I pip froze everything so that Heroku could utilize the exact packages.

I am running gunicorn within the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn -w 4 -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" app:app
```

My runtime.txt:

```
python-3.7.4
```

Locally, the function I'm callling runs fine.

On Heroku, it throws a Value Error:

2020-05-04T19:40:31.074211+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1202, in viewlim_to_dt

2020-05-04T19:40:31.074212+00:00 app[web.1]:     .format(vmin))

```
ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. 
This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

I am watching the logs, which is how I could find out the above.

Is Gunicorn causing this? Why would it act differently in two spots even with pip freeze?

Could someone help me with figuring a better way to debug this?

Comment: Can you describe what you are doing in your code or even share your code ?

Comment: @SebNik I was more or less asking about operating systems. The code is getting executed in the most slightest way. Bad practice that worked on my computer wasn't working when deployed through Gunicorn on Heroku. I cleaned my code up and found the computational bugs. Why it worked one place and not the other is still unknown although after cleaning my code I was able to get it to work. Finally a two day headache has been cleared